# Execute different scripts for snapshot/release builds

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, hudson

Is there a way to execute different post-build scripts depending on whether or not the build was a release build?

My goal is to execute script A for snapshot builds and execute script B for release builds

It seems pretty straight forward to determine if it was a maven release build with the groovy-post-build plugin, like so:

```
if(manager.build.buildVariables.containsKey("MVN_RELEASE_VERSION"))
{
    "cmd /c C:\\test.bat".execute(); // Results in FileNotFound exception.
}
```

However, the groovy plugin gets run in a sandbox, so it doesn't allow you to access the filesystem to execute other scripts, or say grab an artifact to upload to S3.

The other option I tried was to just execute a Windows batch script, however, the variables that get passed to that script does not include the information to determine if it was a release build or not.

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the flexi publish plugin in jenkins, hope it should solve

Comment: Yeah the flexi publish plugin will work for what I'm looking to do. The regex match (from Run Conditional Plugin) will allow the same logic to apply. Matching the expression `^(?=\s*\S).*$` (look for non null) to the label `${ENV,var="MVN_RELEASE_VERSION"}` will use the same logic in the original question. Thanks for the pointers!